# Why do I keep getting a Compile Error in Word?

Tags: vba, compilation, ms-word

Why does this code keep throwing up an compile error in Word?

```
DocNum = DocNum + 1
ActiveDocument.SaveAs 
FileName:="ExtractedPage_" & DocNum & ".docx"
```

It says"Compile error, expected end of statement"?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have the SaveAs and filename on separate lines without a continuation character after SaveAs. Try:

```
DocNum = DocNum + 1
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="ExtractedPage_" & DocNum & ".docx", _
FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
```